# MySQL Union Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have the following query, selecting rows which are found inside that 2 subqueries:

First subquery is to get vehicles, second to get drivers.

That first select is to get values from both subqueries.

```
select
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        count(distinct idClientTruck) as Vehículos,
        round(sum(v_ko)/(v_docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% Docs. Vehículos",
        count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
        round(sum(d_ko)/(d_docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% Docs. Conductores"
        from
        (
            (select     
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as v_docs, 
                wv.idClientTruck as idClientTruck, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as v_ko 
            from
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_vehicle wv on wv.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wv.idstatus=71001
                join client_truck t on t.idclient_truck=wv.idclienttruck and t.idstatus_truckpart=33005
                join widoc_fulfill_vehicle fv on fv.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fv.idwidocvehicle=wv.idwidocvehicle
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wv.idClientTruck
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001         
            where 
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
            ) x

            UNION

            (select 
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as d_docs, 
                wd.idDriver as idDriver, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as d_ko
            from 
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
                join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
                join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
            where 
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
            ) y
        ) group by department,company;
```

But I get this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'y   ) group by department,company' at line 60

Can anyone help me finding this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need aliases for the 2 queries that participate in the UNION, but you do need one for the unioned query:

```
select
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        count(distinct idClientTruck) as Vehículos,
        round(sum(v_ko)/(v_docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% Docs. Vehículos",
        count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
        round(sum(d_ko)/(d_docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% Docs. Conductores"
        from
        (
            select     
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as v_docs,   
                wv.idClientTruck as idClientTruck, 
                null as idDriver,
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as v_ko 
            from
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_vehicle wv on wv.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wv.idstatus=71001
                join client_truck t on t.idclient_truck=wv.idclienttruck and t.idstatus_truckpart=33005
                join widoc_fulfill_vehicle fv on fv.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fv.idwidocvehicle=wv.idwidocvehicle
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wv.idClientTruck
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001         
            where 
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
            UNION
            select 
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as d_docs, 
                null as idClientTruck,
                wd.idDriver as idDriver, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as d_ko
            from 
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
                join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
                join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
            where 
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        ) t group by department,company;
```

Comment: That was my first fix, but query doesn't know column "idDriver" then. It is like values from the second query doesn't reach that first select.Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idDriver' in 'field list'

Comment: Is the column wv.idClientTruck the corresponding column for IdDriver in query 1?

Comment: The unioned query has column names derived from the 1st query. So use `idClientTruck` instead of `idDriver`

Comment: Yes, they represent the same although in different tables.

Comment: See my previous comment.

Comment: But then at the first select I will have like the same row: count(distinct idClientTruck) as Vehículos. I need one row for vehicles and one for drivers.

Comment: Then you must have 2 separate columns. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you man, but with that, vehicles part is perfect, but then all drivers are '0', and drivers documents are null, it is like query get values only from vehicles query and doesn't arrive at drivers query i don't know why.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to do here. My answer was about the syntactical error you get. The logic of your requirement is something that you need to clarify in a separate question.